# Is it possible to change tab header color each filetype in vim?

Tags: vim

If I'm opening .js, .html, .rb and other filetype, is it possible to change tab color each filetype? 
Tab means vim's tab not like space.

Comment: I can't answer your problem, but I recommend giving this a read

https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the format `%#String#` will color with the string hightlight :
- `set tabline=%#String#\ toto`

A script to put in your *vimrc*:

```
function! TabTest()
  let res = ''

  for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
    let i += 1
    " Get open buffer
    let i_window = tabpagewinnr(i)
      let l_buffer = tabpagebuflist(i)
    let i_buffer = l_buffer[i_window - 1]

    " Get type
    let s_type = getbufvar(i_buffer, '&filetype')

    " Set color according to filetype
    let s_color = ''
    if i == tabpagenr()
      let res .= '%#TabLine#'
    elseif 'javascript' == s_type
      let res .= '%#String#'
    elseif 'html' == s_type
      let res .= '%#Comment#'
    else 
      let res .= '%#Normal#'
    endif

    " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
    let res .= '%' . (i + 1) . 'T'

    " Set label text
      let s_buffer = bufname(i_buffer)
    try
      let s_file = split(s_buffer, '/')[-1]
    catch
      let s_file = '[No Name]'
    endtry
      let res .= ' ' . s_file
  endfor

  return res
endfunction

set tabline=%!TabTest()
```

As you are asking for an color hightlight according to the filetype, you must get the filetype of a buffer:
- `let s_type = getbufvar(i_buffer, '&filetype')`

For this you must get the buffer number of the activer buffer in the tab:
- `let i_window = tabpagewinnr(i)`
- `let l_buffer = tabpagebuflist(i)`
- `let i_buffer = l_buffer[i_window - 1]`

Then you must wisely distinguish accroding to the filetype with a if. So you definitely want to hide all this in a function:
`set tabline=%!TabTest()`

More :
`h tabline`
`h statusline`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own `:help 'tabline'` (see also `:help 'statusline'`) for that… and all its supporting code.

Having different colors is the easy part:

```
:set tabline=%#Error#\ foo.js\ %*%#DiffAdd#\ bar.rb\ %*%#Search#\ baz.scss\ %*
```

[image]

It's the code that will determine the correct `tabline` value on various events that won't be trivial *at all*.